# Offset on mobile Safari because of bottom menubar

Tags: css, mobile-safari, vertical-alignment

I have a square on my website, vertically and horizontally centered. This works fine, if i test it in small resolutions on my desktop. But if i open it in Safari on mobile (Ihpone 5S), there's a small offset to the top of the square because of the bottom menubar. Is there any way to fix this?

```
    <div id="content" class="site-content">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">

    <section id="primary" class="content-area col-12">
        <main id="main" class="site-main
        product
        " role="main">


<div class="project_square"></div>

<article id="post-508" class="post-508 post type-post status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail hentry category-product category-projecten">

    <div class="row no-gutters project_top">
        <h1 class="entry-title">Daily Gems</h1>

            <div class="layout_img project_center">
                                    <img src="www.imgurl.com" alt="" />
                            </div>



    </div>

main
{
  display: block;
}
.project_square
{
  position: fixed;
  width: 37.5vw;
  height: 37.5vw;
  background: #fff;
  left: 31.25vw;
  z-index: 101;
  top: 48%;
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

The square should be vertically centered behind the next. And not float above the text (as in the screenshot of mobile).

[Safari Mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6FCv.png) [Desktop browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4hr0.jpg)

Comment: can we see a bit more of your code? like the CSS of the parent element and also maybe the HTML corresponding to that?

Comment: i edited the post. it's a fixed element though, so it's mainly about the safari bar having influence on the positioning.

Comment: any particular reason why youve made it `fixed` position and not positioned it relative to the image or text?

Comment: It's an element that scrolls with you during the whole page, so it has to be on the same spot all the time.

Comment: why does the white square stay stuck in the middle of the screen while scrolling to the bottom of the page? like why do u want it always in the middle of the screen? does it serve a purpose?

Comment: it's part of the website concept :) but it's not really the point here :)

Comment: well, i asked u why it was fixed in the middle of ur screen, and u answered as if it was at least somewhat incidental. im trying to think of ways to fix this. show me the code that surrounds the image. you could wrap that "first page" in a container, and giving it a `width: 100%; height: 100%;` would fix your problem if `html, body { width: 100%; height: 100%; }`

Comment: it doesnt seem to work. When i change the position of the text over the white square from "Position: absolute" to fixed, it seems to be change to the same position as the white square (on desktop and iphone/mobile)

Comment: i never told you to change the `position` of the text... and of course, because `position: fixed` will always position an element relative to the browser window. also it doesnt help that you wont tell me EXACTLY what it is youre trying to achieve...

Comment: I was testing that for myself..
I just want it like on the screenshot of desktop, and then also on mobile safari (as you see on the screenshot the top position is different). Maybe it makes more clear to show the website: https://zoetmulder.eu/projecten/monday-mug/

Comment: i understand what you want to do. i dont understand WHY you want to do it that way. and ive already explained to you what the issue is, so im not sure why youre so confused?

Comment: Why does the why matter in this case? I already explained it's part of the concept for the website. Your solution doesnt work? Thanks for helping though.

Comment: because you might still be able to fulfill your aim while addressing your problem. based on whats currently happening and your issue with it, the solution that i provided above will work, unless youve implemented it incorrectly... but anyways. good luck with that